# ref type, StringBuilder

Tags: c#

I have a string `errMsg` to be printed after an input file is read. After the validations are done, if `success==false` it calls the method `PrintErrorMessage(string)`

```
//Validations 
//First Validation: checks the value of input string realization. 
success = Numerical.Check("Realizations", inputs.realizations.ToString(), out ltester, out errMsg);
sb.AppendLine(errMsg);

//Second Validation: checks the value of the input string diameter.
success = Numerical.Check("Pipe Outside Diameter", inputs.pipeOD.ToString(), out dtester, out errMsg);
sb.AppendLine(errMsg); 
if (!success)
{
    PrintErrorMessage(success, errTitle, sb.ToString());
}
```

Here's the method where I print the error:

```
Streamwriter swpt = new Streamwriter(....);
private void PrintErrorMessage(bool success, string errTitle, string errMsg)
{
    if (!success)
    {
        swRpt.WriteLine(errTitle + errMsg);
    }
}
```

The question is this: Instead of appending the `StringBuilder` at each and every step after each validation, can I use a ref type and pass it in the `PrintErrorMessage` function and append it there?

Comment: `StringBuilder` might be a bad choice here. How big are the strings? Is this code being called in a tight loop? Do you have performance statistics that show this is a problem area?  http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: Yes, and since it is an object it will be passed by reference by default.

Comment: Probably this is only pseudocode because the second test will destroy the result of the first (success). However, from this context, I would say that using StringBuilder is a bit excessive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Instead of appending the stringbuilder at each an everystep after each validation, can I use a ref type and pass it in the PrintErrorMessage function and append it there

You can pass it *without* `ref` and append to it. StringBuilder is a *Reference Type*

Comment: Could you pls tell me how. Do I need to call the PrintErrorMessage  after each validation. I prefer calling it after all the validations are done

Answer (score 4):

Sure. You don't need even to declare a 'ref' type parameter - since StringBuilder is itself a reference type, it is automatically passed by ref.

Comment: Could you pls tell me how. Do I need to call the PrintErrorMessage after each validation. I prefer calling it after all the validations are done